# Why does not size of mysql ibdata2 change?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I set the following configuration in MySQL5.0

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend:max:16000M
```

Though the data increase, size of ibdata2 does not change

Why does not size of mysql ibdata2 change?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably because you haven't written anything to it yet.  InnoDB will reuse existing deleted rows before attempting to write data to new places in the InnoDB tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

You've setup a 2G tablespace in ibdata1, and a 10M tablespace in ibdata2. InnoBase will fill up ibdata1 before it proceeds to extend ibdata2. If you've got less than 2G of data, ibdata2 will not have anything in it.